# Autocomplete-Light channel name conflict

Tags: python, django, autocomplete

I have a Django project containing two apps, Expenses and Sales which both have models named Item. I'm using **django-autocomplete-light** to ease the selection of Item. This works for either Expenses or Sales depending on which channel I register last but the other one wrongly shows the same Items.

**autocomplete_light_registry.py**

```
from sales.models import Item as SalesItem
from expenses.models import Item as ExpenseItem

class ExpenseChannel(autocomplete_light.ChannelBase):
    def query_filter(self, results):
        q = self.request.GET.get('q', None)

        if q:
            if results.model == ExpenseItem:
                results = results.filter(
                    Q(name__icontains=q)
    return results

class SalesChannel(autocomplete_light.ChannelBase):
    def query_filter(self, results):
        q = self.request.GET.get('q', None)

        if q:
            if results.model == SalesItem:
                results = results.filter(
                    Q(name__icontains=q)
    return results

autocomplete_light.register(ExpenseItem, ExpenseChannel, placeholder='Select an item (e)')
autocomplete_light.register(SalesItem, SalesChannel, placeholder='Select an item (s)')
```

**admin.py**

For sales app, similar in expenses

```
import autocomplete_light

class SalesItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    fields = ('item', )
    model = SalesItem
    form = autocomplete_light.modelform_factory(SalesItem)
```

Checking the log when using the autocomplete fields i see the same url being fetched from both views.

> "GET /autocomplete/channel/ItemChannel/?q= HTTP/1.1" 200 1416

How do I configure this so list of sales.Item is returned in Admin Sales view and list of expenses.Item is returned in Admin Expenses view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the channel class is generated in most cases and it's name is generated too. However, you can avoid channel class generation and channel name generation (hopefully, or this would really suck).

From the [registry documentation](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html#autocomplete_light.registry.ChannelRegistry.register_model_channel):

> Three cases are possible:
>
> - specify model class and ModelNameChannel will be generated extending    ChannelBase, with attribute model=model
> - specify a model and a channel    class that does not have a model attribute, and a ModelNameChannel    will be generated, with attribute
>     model=model
> - specify a channel class with a model attribute, and the channel is directly    registered

The solution to avoid channel class generation is to be in the third case: **register a model and channel class with a model attribute**.

**autocomplete_light_registry.py**

```
from sales.models import Item as SalesItem
from expenses.models import Item as ExpenseItem

class ExpenseChannel(autocomplete_light.ChannelBase):
    placeholder='Select an item (e)'
    model = ExpenseItem

    def query_filter(self, results):
        q = self.request.GET.get('q', None)

        if q:
            if results.model == ExpenseItem:
                results = results.filter(
                    Q(name__icontains=q)
    return results

class SalesChannel(autocomplete_light.ChannelBase):
    model = SalesItem
    placeholder = 'Select an item (s)'

    def query_filter(self, results):
        q = self.request.GET.get('q', None)

        if q:
            if results.model == SalesItem:
                results = results.filter(
                    Q(name__icontains=q)
    return results

autocomplete_light.register(ExpenseChannel)
autocomplete_light.register(SalesChannel)
```

That would work up to 0.7rc2.

Starting 0.7rc3 (to be released when the pending issue is closed), register() has a new keyword argument, `channel_name`, which you may use.

**But** you should be careful with your code, it seems like the query_filter() implementation from your classes is the same as the default implementation ...

Comment: Thank you for explaining how to do this and also for adding the new feature with `channel_name` when registering. Both solutions works as expected and I will use the the keyword when it's released to save code lines.

Comment: In case you didn't get the email from the mailing list, it is released: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autocomplete-light/ yes the channel_name feature is to keep code elegant in some cases and the bare registration feature is to not get in your way in some other cases